# How to I format a cell in a DataGrid to show a % symbol after

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

This is what I have treid so far, when it formats the cell... it gives me, for example, 1,000.00% if i give it the value 10.00.
`dgWeightTable.Columns["Fat (%)"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "P";`
How do I make it give me 10.00% back? I'm getting the values from a database I made by the way

Comment: 1.0 is 100%, 10.0 is 1000%, divide by 100 if you are storing (0%-100%) percentages in your database?

Comment: I'm storing them as floats in my database... should I change that?

Comment: Float is Ok, you should probably store values in the range `0.0 - 1.0`. Or format the value yourself in the `CellFormatting` event (no default format handling needed in this case).

Comment: So when I get the value, Divide it by 100 then? would that work? or is the a better way of doing that?

Comment: `.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00 '%'"`